# Missing Auth Session in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

Here is my problem: on one specific page I get only blank white page, without any errors and messages. When I allow this page using $this->Auth->allow(); method I see, that $this->Auth->user(); return nothing. 
And, this I see this problem only on this page.

Can you help me ?

Code:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();     

    $this->flatVariables();

    $this->Auth->allow('search','view');
}
function edit() {
    debug($this->Auth->user());
    exit();
}
```

*P.S. Sorry for english.*

Answer (score 0):

Check for below possibilities.

1. Check if u wrote layout = ajax in controller.
2. check if u wrote autoRender = false in controller.
3. check if u just exit out of script while debugging.
4. and more important set debug mode to 2 so u will notify for possible error.

Comment: I made all you said, but I get the same problem.